# Is there generally understood set theory term for $A \cap B \setminus C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

I'm interested in formalising/documenting a program plotting Venn charts (well UpSet plots actually). Is there a term that can unambiguously refer to the coloured partition of the visualisation below (obtained from Wolfram alpha from $A \cap B \setminus C$) in relation to $A$ and $B$? It was previously referred to as *distinct* intersection of $A$ and $B$ (because it does not include the intersection of $A$ and $B$ with any other set) - is there a formal term for this concept?

[image: set overlap illustration]

Edit: in general I am interested in a case of $n$ sets. I am looking for a generic name for a region of an intersection of $k$ sets ($k \leq n$) such that it is *exclusive* to the sets forming the intersection this is it excludes overlap with any other set that do not for this $k$ intersection.

Comment: $(A\cap B)\setminus C = A\cap (B\setminus C)$, so the expression is technically unambiguous.  It is still bad form in my opinion to write this without parentheses since it is not immediately apparent to a beginner that this should be the case.

Comment: As for if there is a specific name for that set or operation... none that I am aware of beyond the obvious "intersection of $A,B$ and $C^c$" or "Intersection of $A$ and $B$ without $C$" etc...  I hesitate to say something like "The region simultaneously occupied by $A$ and $B$ and no others" in general because the image only alludes to the additional set $C$ but does not preclude there existing other unpictured sets which may also occupy a portion of that region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not any commonly used term for this.  Simply writing it as $(A\cap B)\setminus C$ or $A\cap B\cap C^c$ (with ${C}^c$ referring to the complement of $C$) would be a reasonable choice.  If you want to refer to it in words, you could say something like "the region that is in $A$ and $B$ but not $C$", or "the intersection of $A$ and $B$ and the complement of $C$".  You could also say something like "the region that is *only* in $A$ and $B$".  I would strongly recommend against "distinct intersection"; that's not the way "distinct" is normally used in mathematics.

Comment: Thank you. I like `distinct` because it is a single word that can be used as an argument value in a programming implementation that I am preparing [here](https://github.com/krassowski/complex-upset/pull/78) to achieve a result demonstrated [there](https://github.com/hms-dbmi/UpSetR/issues/72#issuecomment-597804658). Would you recommend a different choice of up to three words for a general case? Should I edit my question to reflect that I am interested in a general case of *n* sets, and the A, B, C are just examples?

Comment: I'm thinking about this region as being a partition of $A \cap B$ that is *exclusive* to $A$ and $B$ but I am afraid of using `exclusive` either as it has yet another meaning in set theory.

Comment: "Exclusive" is a reasonable choice.  I don't think there's any single word you can use and expect people to understand what you mean without seeing at least one example.

Comment: Another word you might use is "exact", to indicate you are listing exactly the sets that your region is in.